# Unity 3D: C# NPC Colliding each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know how to stop my NPC's colliding into the player, I just can't seem to figure out how I can get them to stop colliding into each other as well as the player?

The NPC's have a tag of "AI", I have tried a few things now but i really can't figure this out?

Here is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AI : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform target;
public int moveSpeed = 5;
public int rotationSpeed = 2;
public Transform myTransform;
public float minDistance = 0.1f;


void Awake ()
{
    myTransform = transform;
}

void Start ()
{
    target = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
}

void Update ()
{
    Vector3 Distance = target.position - myTransform.position;

    if(Distance.sqrMagnitude>minDistance*minDistance)
    {
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean they should be able to pass right through each other? Or avoid each other altogether?

Comment: I mean having a distance set on all of the NPC's as well as having a distance from the player, when they approach the player, they will all gather close together, i want to try get a distance from all of the NPC's and players of like 1
Can you help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the collider component on your AI GameObject and either remove it or check the IsTrigger option.

[More on IsTrigger:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html)

> Is the collider a trigger?
>
> A trigger doesn't register a collision with an incoming Rigidbody. Instead, it sends OnTriggerEnter, OnTriggerExit and OnTriggerStay message when a rigidbody enters or exits the trigger volume.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! i still can't seem to get this to work, I tried having a box collider on them and they all jib out... know of a tutorial of what you mean?

Comment: Did you try removing the colliders? The primitive unity GameObjects are created with colliders so you might have some on the AI or its children.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a distance from the player and a distance from other NPCs as the mechanism for not colliding with each other, they may conflict.

For example, an NPC might be told by the code to move further away from the player, this could mean moving too close to another NPC, so the two commands conflict with each other.

A more modular approach might be to separate the commands into methods:

```
AvoidPlayer()
{
    // Code here to move away from player.
}

AvoidNPC()
{
    // Code here to move away from NPC.
}
```

You can then call each one when it is appropriate. If you want to ensure there is always a minimum distance between NPCs and the player *and* NPCs and each other, bear in mind the logical problem of the conflicting commands.